# Smoothly fitting texture tiles using alpha gradient on edges

Tags: libgdx, graphics, alpha-blending

I'm trying to draw a background texture with tiles that I'll rotate and mirror to create a maze. Here is a sample tile:

[image: sample tile]

As you can see, I use an alpha gradient on the borders. If I'd use a sharp border instead, you'd notice the border between a tile and another because these shadows and glows are not perfectly symmetrical.

So far it works OK, but I've noticed there is a slightly darker spot where two tiles connect:

[image: dark spot]

I used Photoshop to create these gradients, and was very careful to make sure these gradients are linear and start exactly where the next gradient ends, so that the total alpha of every pixel add up to exactly one.

I'm using a `SpriteBatch` to draw these textures and use the default blending mode (I don't set any blend function at all). Apparently I'd need some blending function whose output will be the sum of both image's alphas and the average of their colors. Is this the default mode (if so, I guess my picture's alpha gradients are not perfectly linear)? And if not, what should I set my `SpriteBatch`'s blend function to?

**Edit:** So I tried `batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_DST_ALPHA)` and it fixed the dark spot, but now the textures I draw on top look messed up, even if I revert it back to the old blending mode right after drawing my tiles.